# Phase response of an LTI-system

Tags: signal-analysis, linear-systems, impulse-response

I've got an LTI-system such as follows:
$$y'(t)+{2} y(t)={5} x(t-{3}), t>0,
  \\ \\ y(0)=0 \ \text{ ja } x(t)=0, \ t<0.$$
From this i've already figured out the transfer function:
$$H(f)=\frac{5\cdot e^{\left(-\mathrm{i}\right)\cdot 2\cdot \pi\cdot f\cdot 3}}{2+\mathrm{i}\cdot 2\cdot \pi\cdot f}$$
And the amplitude response:
$$\frac{5}{\sqrt{4+\left(2\cdot \pi\cdot f\right)^2}}$$
However, I seem to have trouble with the phase response. I know the formula for phase response is as follows:
$$θ(f)=arg[H(f)]$$
But I still have some trouble using it. The denominator would go as follows I think:
$$arg(2+i*2*pi*f)=arctan(\frac{Im}{Re})=arctan(\frac{2*pi*f}{2})$$
But i'm a bit confused about the numerator, and the exponential within it. Is the imaginary part of the numerators argument pi times 6, or does the exponential stay? Or perhaps there is no real part at all?

Comment: $\arg e^{i \theta} = \theta$.  Does that help?

Comment: further help: Do you see how your numerator has magnitude 5 and phase versus frequency $2\pi f 3$? If $H(f)$ was just your numerator the answer should be very clear. So now if you know the phase and magnitude versus frequency of your denominator and you know how to divide the two (What is the phase of $e^{j\phi_1}/e^{j\phi_2}$???), you will have your answer.

Comment: @TimWescott The way I would continue would be to get the 2*pi*f*3 from the exponential, by the formula you suggested, and multiplying it by five, getting 30*pi*f. Would this be correct?

Comment: When you have three factors of functions of frequency, let's say $H(f)G(f)E(f)$, their phase function is $\angle H(f) + \angle G(f) + \angle E(f)$. Does that help any further? Keep in mind that positive real numbers have zero phase.

Comment: @GKH I think that does help a bit, but something still doesn't seem right. If I take the real number 5 and the exponential seperately, as you recommended, I end up with arg(5) = 0, and arg(e^i*2*pi*f*3) = 6*pi*f, which would end up with arctan(6*pi*f)(?). I'm quite sure that I am still missing something.

Comment: @GKH So from this I would derive that the argument for the phase response would be $$θ(f)=arg[H(f)] =arctan(6*\pi*f)-arctan(\frac{2*\pi*f}{2})$$, which makes sense to me, but still seems incorrect.

Comment: @TootsieRoll OK, let's see: $\angle 5 = 0$ and $\angle e^{-j2\pi 3f} = -6\pi f$. Since the other factor is $1/(2+j2\pi f)$, its phase would be $\angle 1 - \angle (2+j2\pi f)$. You can verify this by checking the argument of a complex number $1/z = 1/(re^{j\theta}) = (1/r)e^{-j\theta}$, that is, $\angle z = -\theta$. So, given that, what is the total phase in your case?

Comment: @TootsieRoll, I think you need to try again. :) In a previous comment you mentioned that $arg(e^{-i2\pi 3f}) = -6\pi f$. Why don't you use it now? Finally, I just see an arctan(...) as your answer, rather than a sum of the phases of your three functions of f (or two functions, if you consider 5 as a zero phase constant).

Comment: $$θ(f)=arg[H(f)] =(-6*\pi*f)-arctan(\frac{2*\pi*f}{2})$$ @GKH I see, I took arctan for the both parts instead of the latter. This should be the phase response.

Comment: @TootsieRoll This one looks much better ;)